# After log4j1 migration to log4j2 default configuration is being used

Tags: log4j, log4j2, properties-file

I have added the following to my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also added the system properties in order to get the experimental support :

```
System.setProperty("log4j2.debug", "true");
System.setProperty("log4j1.compatibility","true");
System.setProperty("log4j.configuration","C:/playground/HelloLogging/src/main/resources/log4j.properties");
```

and followed the instructions on the apache site:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html
and
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/compatibility.html

I want to keep using my v1 ***log4j.properties***

For some reason, the program runs with **default configuration**.
not reading my properties file and not writing to the output log file

Did anyone succeeded to use log4j2 compatibility feature?

The log says:

> No Root logger was configured, creating default ERROR-level Root
> logger with Console appender

Attached bellow the full trace:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -Dlog4j1.compatibility=true -Dlog4j2.debug=true -Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=trace -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///C:/Logging/src/main/resources/log4j.properties "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=54099:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\playground\HelloLogging\target\classes;C:\Users\maryb\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-1.2-api\2.13.0\log4j-1.2-api-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\maryb\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.13.0\log4j-api-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\maryb\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.13.0\log4j-core-2.13.0.jar" com.mkyong.HelloExample
DEBUG StatusLogger Using ShutdownCallbackRegistry class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=UNCACHED (user specified null, default is UNCACHED)
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock does not support precise timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Took 0.121267 seconds to load 238 plugins from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 46 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@49993335]...
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration started for context[name=18b4aac2] at URI null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@49993335) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'ConfigurationFactory' found 6 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Yaml support, ConfigurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.yaml.YamlConfigurationFactory is inactive
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Missing dependencies for Json support, ConfigurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.json.JsonConfigurationFactory is inactive
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@5e853265
DEBUG StatusLogger Not in a ServletContext environment, thus not loading WebLookup plugin.
DEBUG StatusLogger Apache Log4j Core 2.13.0 initializing configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@59e5ddf
DEBUG StatusLogger Installed 1 script engine
DEBUG StatusLogger Oracle Nashorn version: 1.8.0_231, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Core' found 123 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 15 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createLoggers(={})
DEBUG StatusLogger Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
DEBUG StatusLogger createAppenders(={})
WARN StatusLogger No Root logger was configured, creating default ERROR-level Root logger with Console appender
DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Converter' found 46 plugins
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-2
DEBUG StatusLogger Configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@59e5ddf initialized
DEBUG StatusLogger Starting configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@59e5ddf
DEBUG StatusLogger Started configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@59e5ddf OK.
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@4361bd48...
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@4361bd48 OK
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@6302bbb1
TRACE StatusLogger Reregistering context (1/1): '18b4aac2' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@49993335
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector
DEBUG StatusLogger Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=DefaultConsole-2
TRACE StatusLogger Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock does not support precise timestamps.
TRACE StatusLogger Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
DEBUG StatusLogger Reconfiguration complete for context[name=18b4aac2] at URI C:\playground\HelloLogging\src\main\resources\log4j.properties (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@49993335) with optional ClassLoader: null
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
DEBUG StatusLogger LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@49993335] started OK.
09:37:08.310 [main] ERROR com.mkyong.HelloExample - This is error : mkyong
09:37:08.315 [main] FATAL com.mkyong.HelloExample - This is fatal : mkyong
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopping LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@49993335]
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopping LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@49993335]...
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=DefaultConsole-2]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@59e5ddf...
TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-2
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-2, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender DefaultConsole-2 stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@59e5ddf OK
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@49993335] with status true

Process finished with exit code 0

enter code here
```

Comment: Since loggers are usually static fields, Log4j might initialize **before** you set those system properties in code. You need to set those property using JVM `-Dproperty=value` command parameters.

Comment: I have added the properties in the vm options and also added the properties file path to the classpath of the projects. I have verified it from inside the program, the properties are set. 
{code}
CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%\;C:/myProj/src/main/resources/log4j.properties
{code}
Looks like the properties file is being read, but it is unrecognized. I get the following error:
{code}
WARN StatusLogger No Root logger was configured, creating default ERROR-level Root logger with Console appender
{code}
any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Can you add the status logger logs to your question (edit your question)? The problem might also be in your `log4j.properties` file.

Comment: thanks, I have added. The same log4j.properties was used with version 1.2.17
I want to use it as is in version 2x

Answer (score 3):

Since Log4j 2.x also has a properties configuration format, to distinguish the two formats, you need to use:

- the `log4j2.configurationFile` property to specify a list of strictly Log4j 2.x configuration files,
- the `log4j.configuration` property to specify a single Log4j 1.2 configuration file.

In your case replace `log4j.configurationFile` with `log4j.configuration`.

Comment: thanks! this looks better.
now it did read the DEBUG and failed on the stdout and file.
This is the log:
DEBUG StatusLogger Parsing for [root] with value=[DEBUG, stdout, file].
DEBUG StatusLogger Level token is [DEBUG].
DEBUG StatusLogger Logger root level set to DEBUG
DEBUG StatusLogger Parsing appender named "stdout".
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to create Appender org.apache.logging.log4j.ConsoleAppender due to ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.logging.log4j.ConsoleAppender

Comment: I have found the issue:
when I did search/replace for org.apache.log4j to org.apache.logging.log4j,
I have replaced the log4j.properties file as well. but I need to keep the log4j.properties file in the old log4j1 format. Therefore, after reverting this change, it started working. thanks